# Unable to Upload Image but Server response indicates success

Tags: flutter, dart

Each time I try to upload an image using http multipart, I get success response in less than a second, which is weird and indicates that the image wasn't uploaded. How do I get over this issue please:

```
Future<UpdatedUserDataModel> updateUserData(
      {String accessToken, String field, String value}) async {
    String params = '?access_token=$accessToken';
    String url = AppStrings.apiBase + AppStrings.updateUserData + params;

    Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"};

    //Prepare Multipart request
    http.MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest(
      'POST',
      Uri.parse(url),
    );
    request.fields['api_key'] = AppStrings.apiKey;
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    request.files.add(
      await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
        field,
        value,
        filename: 'cover_image',
        contentType: MediaType('image', value.split('.').last),
      ),
    );

    //Send request
    final response = await request.send();

    //Decode response stream here...
    
  }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks, I just did.